# CKeditor: don't lose focus when clicking another element

Tags: ckeditor

Someone know how to use the CKEditor focus manager?

I need to keep the focus on the current editor session when I click on several DOM elements?

Look at [this page](http://media.dday.it/roby/editor4/samples/inlineall.html)

The three column under the slider are editable.

Imagine that I'm writing in the first column. When I want to insert a youtube video I past a youtube URL in the text field above the slider, but when I click on the text input field I lose the editor focus. So I have to click again on editor and then I can push the button "insert media".

Is possible with FocusManager to keep focus on the current editor when I click on some page elements?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [editorInstance.focusManager.add() method](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.focusManager-method-add). This should solve your problem.

Comment: I try with this code:


`var focusManager = new CKEDITOR.focusManager( editor );
var header = document.getElementById( 'header' );
editor.focusManage.add( header );`

where header is my toolbar. Is not working... this feature is not well documented! (i also update the sample)

Comment: Use `CKEDITOR.dom.element` instead of native element: `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.focusManager.add( CKEDITOR.document.getById( 'header' ), 1 )`

Comment: I'm learning javascript now so maybe I'm doing some errors, but if I use your code the editor tolbar doesn't appear with no error in javascript console!

Comment: I notice that you are a core developer of CKeditor so I suppose that you are right and I'm doing something wrong, but I try several solution and sometimes I lose focus and sometimes the editor doesn't appear. 

I have multiple inline editor on my page so I have multiple session, so I imagine that I have to add the header to the focus manager on every instance.

Comment: ok I solve partially the issue!
`var aggiunta = new CKEDITOR.dom.element( document.getElementById( 'header' ) );`
`var editor = CKEDITOR.currentInstance;`
`CKEDITOR.currentInstance.focusManager.add( aggiunta, 1 )`

Now the header is added to the focus manager, but I have multiple editor in my page and I think that CKEditor can add an element only for one editor. By the way now in my sample the textbox call always the same editor... I think that to accomplish the result I need I must add the element to the current editor and remove the element from the focus manager onBlur right?

Comment: Uhm I try also using event but i obtain only a lot of editor on my page :D

With my low skill in impossible to solve this enigma! :D

Comment: I've done it!!! 

[Sample](http://media.dday.it/roby/editor4/samples/inlineall.html)